# Use Craft.postActionRequest in frontend template

Tags: templating, javascript

Until now I've always done backend plugin development but my next task is to create a homepage with craft. To make an Ajax request I used `Craft.postActionRequest` but if I try this in my frontend template I always receive the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Craft is not defined`

I've tried to include `{%- includejsresource "js/craft.js" first -%}` but it does not work. Of course I could just create a normal request via Ajax/jQuery but I would like to do it with craft methods...

So my question: what do I have to do, to get access to craft.js library?
edit: Just like this https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/controllers#posting-to-controller-actions-with-javaScript

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The global `Craft` object available in the Control Panel is exposed in the `craft.js` file, which is a bundle containing most of the JavaScript code used in Craft's Control Panel (i.e. admin area).

*This file is not meant to be used in your front end!*

The `craft.js` file has dependencies on other CP-only JavaScript files, and weighs – by itself – a whopping ~250 kb minified, which is *a lot* of bytes to force on your end users just because you'd like to use a tiny part of the library in your front end code. Additionally, because the file is only meant to be used with core functionality in the Control Panel, it can be updated/changed by Pixel & Tonic at any time (i.e. any time Craft is updated), possibly breaking your custom code which depends on it.

Instead of using the whole `craft.js` package, I'd strongly advice you to cherry pick (i.e. copy and paste) any methods or functionality you need from `craft.js` to a custom JavaScript bundle. For specific functionality (e.g. AJAX requests), you might also consider using other, established open source libraries (like SuperAgent, Axios or even jQuery).

Comment: +1 for [SuperAgent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/)... a perfect AJAX library when jQuery is overkill.